# Invisible edit in the queue

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of suggested edits seems to include own edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109630/number-of-suggested-edits-seems-to-include-own-edits)

If I have a tag wiki edit in the queue, I cannot approve/reject it, but the queue still shows that there is one item there. When I click on the tab, it says there is nothing there.

It should say there is nothing pending in the queue if there is nothing that the user can do.