# Don't tell me that there are suggested edits if I can't see them

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of suggested edits seems to include own edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109630/number-of-suggested-edits-seems-to-include-own-edits)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/ shows me (6k user) this:

[image]

And the mouseover tooltip says

> suggested edits to posts pending approval

However, when I click on that link, it says:

> There are no pending suggested edits to review!

I strongly assume the two (Yup, [there is a two in the orange box](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/4012)) suggested edits are the tag wiki edits I just submitted. Whatever it may be, please don't tell me that there are suggested edits if I can't review them‽

On a side note, is the exclamation mark after *There are no pending suggested edits to review* really necessary? It's not that exciting ...

Comment: Wait, there's a two in that orange-box?

Comment: Personally, I'd split this. Keep the "hide that number if there's nothing to approve" here, and open up a separate question on meta-tex for the color-thingy.

Comment: @doncherry The color choice makes it unreadable to all. You might want to bring this up on [meta.tex.se]; we had [the same thing on Gaming](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1809/hot-brown-on-brown-action-in-review), but it was eventually changed.

Comment: @lunboks & Bobby: Thanks for the suggestions, I did as you suggested.

Comment: The exclamation point is not used when writing something exciting.