# Review bubble shows own edit requests

Tags: bug, review, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of suggested edits seems to include own edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109630/number-of-suggested-edits-seems-to-include-own-edits)

I have the privilege to approve tag wiki edits but not to edit tag wikis without approval.

If I propose a tag wiki edit, then the review notification shows a review that needs action. However there is nothing in the review tab (as I cannot approve my own edit).

The notification should not show for reviews that I cannot actually action.

Comment: @animuson Looks like an exact duplicate to me.