# Minor suggested-edits notification bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of suggested edits seems to include own edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109630/number-of-suggested-edits-seems-to-include-own-edits)

It seems that I've located a minor bug with the little suggested edits flag.

[image: Flags]

I see a flag for 4 suggested edits, even though none are available for me to review.  It's not a lag, or a sync delay, but rather because **I** have submitted 2 tag-wiki and 2 tag-wiki-excerpts.  (4 total.)

Having less than 20k rep, my tag edits require review, but being mine, I can't approve them either.  So I'm stuck with that numbered notification until there are enough people around to approve (or reject, I suppose) my proposed tag edits, as you can see below.

[image: Flags bug]

Not exactly a big deal, but it seemed worth bringing to the SE team's attention.

Comment: I think this is by-design.

Comment: I've noticed that too on stackoverflow...can't speak about by design, or why it is though, but I agree.

Comment: Are you sure [those 4 flags](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nduKQ.png) are for suggested edits? I don't have 10K anywhere but as much as I know those 4 flags are not for suggested edits.

Comment: @hims056: Pardon his word choice, but that bubble represents the number of pending suggested edits. The bubble for the number of pending *flags* appears to the *left* of the review link (if you have that privilege).

Comment: @animuson - Okay that means users with less than 10K don't see suggested edit's count ([at the right side of review link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nduKQ.png)). Because I don't (can't) see it.

Comment: @hims056: Hmmm, that may be so. I don't really remember.

Comment: @hims056 Yes, apologies for the confusing word choice... wasn't sure what to call that bubble thing, and in retrospect, calling it a flag was a poor choice (and probably explains why I couldn't find my question's dupe with the search feature).  But it most definitely is for pending **edits**, not pending *flags.*